# Firebase python insert

Tags: python, firebase

Following the official documentation from firebase i found how to create insite collection a new document with attributes.

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'statuses').document()
doc_ref.set({
    u'power': -1
})
```

But on farebase, insite a document, you can put attributes also you can place new collection (as attribute).

My question is how can i add a new collection with my own ID and insite this new collection with new attributes?

I just created an example on firebase to show what i don't know how to add it using python.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
room_a_ref = db.collection(u'rooms').document(u'roomA')
message_ref = room_a_ref.collection(u'messages').document(u'message1')
```